# Program not recieving messages on non-blocking UDP socket

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, p2p, winsock2

So I have an application in C++ which has classes relating to network functionality. In a function I have made the socket for two clients that are meant to communicate with each other non-blocking via the following:

```
int check;
check = WSAAsyncSelect(sock, aWindow, 0, 0);
```

During the program loop each client program has functions which should send and recieve messages to/from one another. As mentioned the socket is non-blocking so the program loop runs indefinitely as it should do and each client sends messages to the other apparently fine via the following code:

```
socketConfirm =  sendto(sock,
                 (char*) playerStats, sizeof(Message), 0, (SOCKADDR *) & toAddr, sizeof (toAddr));
```

However when the recieving function is called:

```
socketConfirm = recvfrom(sock, (char*)player2Stats, sizeof(Message), 0,
                         (sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromAddrSize);
```

And immediately after this the WSAGetLastError() function is called:

```
if(socketConfirm == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
    }
```

An error code of 10022 is returned and clearly no message is being recieved by either client as the player representing each client on the screen of the other client does not move as inputs are applied and I was wondering if the reason that the messages were not being recieved could be deduced by this error code or if there is another problem that is causing the messages to not be recieved.

Comment: `10022` is `WSAEINVAL`. Documents of `recvfrom` in MSDN say: `The socket has not been bound with bind, or an unknown flag was specified, or MSG_OOB was specified for a socket with SO_OOBINLINE enabled, or (for byte stream-style sockets only) len was zero or negative.`. It look like you does not bind the socket.

Comment: If the socket is bound the error 10035 is returned.

Comment: After removing the break point at the line: error = WSAGetLastError(); the program functions however it appears that each client is sending a message to itself as the second player character moves in tandem with the 1st client player input (which it shouldn't because the second player movement should be governed by the input of the other client).

Comment: `10035` is `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`. It is normally since your socket is non-blocking and there is no data to read.

Comment: Ye but presumably there should be data to read once the 2nd client sends data to the 1st and the sendto function is definitely working as there are no errors being reported in that function - so I suppose the question is why is the data not being recieved, when the recvfrom () function is being called?

Comment: Even sendto() is success it does not mean the data is already arrived in the other end. You should check for the readiness of the data before trying to read by using select().